# How to efficiently replace long strings by their index for SQL Server inserts?

Tags: sql-server, string, replace, view, triggers

I have a very large `DataTable`-Object which I need to import from a client into an MS SQL-Server database via ODBC.

The original Data-Table has two columns:
* First column is the `Office Location` (quite a long string)
* Second column is a `booking value` (integer)

Now I am looking for the most efficient way to insert these data into an external SQL-Server. My goal is to replace each office location automatically by an index instead using the full string because each location occurs VERY often in the initial table.

Is this possible via a trigger or via a view on the SQL-server?

At the end I want to insert the data without touching them in my script because this is very slow for these large amount of data and let the optimization done by the SQL Server.

I expect that if I do INSERT the data including the Office location, that SQL Server looks up an index for an already imported location and then use just this index. And if the location did not already exist in the index table / view then it should create a new entry here and then use the new index.

Here a sample of the data I need to import via ODBC into the SQL-Server:

```
OfficeLocation             | BookingValue
EU-Germany-Hamburg-Ostend1 | 12
EU-Germany-Hamburg-Ostend1 | 23
EU-Germany-Hamburg-Ostend1 | 34
EU-France-Paris-Eifeltower | 42
EU-France-Paris-Eifeltower | 53
EU-France-Paris-Eifeltower | 12
```

What I do need on the SQL-Server is something like these 2 tables as a result:

```
OId|BookingValue      OfficeLocation             |Oid
  1|12                EU-Germany-Hamburg-Ostend1 | 1
  1|23                EU-France-Paris-Eifeltower | 2
  1|43
  2|42
  2|53
  2|12
```

My initial idea was, to write the data into a temp-table and have something like an intelligent TRIGGER (or a VIEW?) to react on any INSERT into this table to create the 2 desired (optimized) tables.

Any hint are more than welcome!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If the data is already in a table why do you need to insert it? You need to provide some context here so others know what you are trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your model, as you should define your office locations in a dedicated table, then use a foreign key to refer to it by ID. Then you can easily index on it, and won't have to duplicate the label indefinitely. You'll have to write your own code to maintain your office locations table though, and you should definitely avoid using table triggers as much as possible. Also take a look at the [ADO.net framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET).

Comment: Sample data and desired result would help here.   The question is currently too unclear to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the fast feedback. I edited the original question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a view with an `INSERT` trigger to handle this. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Locations (
    OId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null PRIMARY KEY,
    OfficeLocation varchar(500) not null UNIQUE
)
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Bookings (
    OId int not null,
    BookingValue int not null
)
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.CombinedBookings
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        OfficeLocation,
        BookingValue
    FROM
        dbo.Bookings b
            INNER JOIN
        dbo.Locations l
            ON
                b.OId = l.OId
GO
CREATE TRIGGER CombinedBookings_Insert
ON dbo.CombinedBookings
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO Locations (OfficeLocation)
    SELECT OfficeLocation
    FROM inserted where OfficeLocation not in (select OfficeLocation from Locations)

    INSERT INTO Bookings (OId,BookingValue)
    SELECT OId, BookingValue
    FROM
          inserted i
              INNER JOIN
          Locations l
              ON
                  i.OfficeLocation = l.OfficeLocation
```

As you can see, we first add to the locations table any missing locations and then populate the bookings table.

A similar trigger can cope with Updates. I'd generally let the Locations table just grow and not attempt to clean it up (for no longer referenced locations) with triggers. If growth is a concern, a periodic job will usually be good enough.

Be aware that some tools (such as bulk inserts) may not invoke triggers, so those will not be usable with the above view.